# Observer not called in Room livedata return type

Tags: android, android-room, dao

I have a utils, an activity, a dao and an entity.

I am using Room library for storing data.

For the first time, the observer is called but when I use insert query, it doesn't seem to notify my observer for the results.

Here is my code
**Dbutils:**

```
public class Dbutils{

StickerPacksDao mydao;

    public Dbutils(StickerPacksDao dao){
    this.mydao=dao;
    }

public void updateRows(){
new UpdateRows(StaticObj.getStickerPackRows).execute();
}
    public class UpdateRows extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        List<StickerPackRow> insertRows;

        public UpdateRows(List<StickerPackRow> insertRows) {
            this.insertRows = insertRows;
            this.deleteRows=deleteRows;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            stickerPacksDao.insert(this.insertRows);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            if(updateListener!=null){
                updateListener.updated();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Activity:**

```
onCreate(){
        appDatabase= Room.databaseBuilder(this,AppDatabase.class,"mydb").build();
observer=new Observer<List<StickerPackRow>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<StickerPackRow> stickerPackRows) {
                if(stickerPackRows!=null){
                   showSnackBar("changed");
                }
            }
        };
  appDatabase.getStickerPacksDao().getStickerPacksAsLiveData().observe(this,observer);
Dbutils dbutils=new Dbutils(  appDatabase.getStickerPacksDao())
dbutils.updateRows();
}
```

**Dao:**

```
@Dao
public interface StickerPacksDao {

    @Query("select * from stickerpacks order by sno DESC")
     public LiveData<List<StickerPackRow>> getStickerPacksAsLiveData();


    @Query("select * from stickerpacks order by sno DESC")
     List<StickerPackRow> getStickerPacks();

    @Insert(onConflict=OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
     void insert(List<StickerPackRow> stickerPackRows);

}
```

Comment: You need to use live data/mutable live data for this.You need to put List<StickerPackRow> in liveData/MutableLiveData then in the doInBackground method you need to call postData of the live data object .Then you can achieve your goal

Comment: this is an alternate way.but thanks for that.

Comment: As mentioned in android Room docs, Observer will call whenever the db updated.But that is not happening here. This is the problem.
@SIVAKUMAR.J

Comment: @ Vimal chandhru - ur comments is correct.But where u register the observer.Then only that observer will call. In other words which observer is observing the room data base changes only that oberser will call.